# What is the equivalent of sinonStub.callsArg(2).returns({}) in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking, sinon

Some code we've inherited from a supplier is using

```
uploadStub.callsArg(2).returns({})
```

in Sinon to mock out the callback to a stubbed function. We're migrating to Jest and I'm struggling to find an equivalent.

The original function call being

```
Upload(req, res, async function (error) { ... })
```

It's this third arg which is a callback that I want to become a mock so the test can return an actual value.

`jestcodemods` has [this PR](https://github.com/skovhus/jest-codemods/pull/357) which suggests

```
apiStub.mockImplementation((...args) => args[2]())
```

which would call the callback but not create a mocked version of it.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the `jestcodemods` solution works with no need to make it return a value.